# i3 toggle to and from workspace?

Tags: i3

I have a `bindsym` keybinding for `$mod+y` that focuses YouTube whereever it may be,

```
bindsym $mod+y [title="YouTube"] focus
```

Is there a way to make a subsequent push, when the window is already focused, send me back? I can have a different button that sends me back,

```
i3-msg workspace back_and_forth
```

But is there a way to make the same button conditionally send me bac if the window is already focused?